# Differentiability and Continuity for multivariable functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

I have encountered these 2 claims in one textbook, asking whether they are true or false. Searching through the web, however, I was not able to correctly answer them(even understand their concepts). It would be grateful if you can help me.

$1)$ If a function $f(x,y)$ is differentiable at $(a,b)$, then $f$ has partial derivatives with respect to both $x$ and $y$ there. 
$2)$ If a function $f(x,y)$ is differentiable at $(a,b)$, then all the first-order partial derivatives of $f$ are continuous at $(a,b)$.

Comment: Presumably those would be answered in the same textbook where you found the claims.  For instance, what is that textbook's definition of *differentiable*?

Comment: There is no indication about these concepts indeed, that was the major reason why I posted this question here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) is true.  This is usually part of the definition of *differentiable*.

2) is false.  A typical counterexample is $f(x,y) = \frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2}$ at $(0,0)$.  Both partial derivatives exist at $(0,0)$, and have value $0$.  But away from $(0,0)$,
\begin{align*}
   \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= \frac{y^2(y^2-x^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \\
   \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} &= \frac{2x^3y}{(x^2+y^2)^2}
\end{align*}
and these derivatives do not approach $0$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$.